# How to open InfoTemplate programmatically?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Could somebody help me?
How to open InfoTemplate programmatically???
Using of FeatureLayer.selectFeatures(...) not helps.
Here is example:
http://jsfiddle.net/gfV2K/
When I click on the map then single feature selected and InfoTemplate is opened.
But when I click some feature in the grid then single feature selected and InfoTemplate isn't opened!
So how to open InfoTemplate in this case? May be there is a way to simulate this behavior (for example by calling map.click() event)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using setFeatures() and show() on the map's infoWindow (which by default is an instance of [esri/dijit/Popup](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/popup-amd.html)). You'll want to call clearFeatures() and hide() before calling setFeatures and show. I also recommend waiting until the map finishes navigating to the new center before calling setFeatures and show. This is easy since centerAt() returns a deferred so you can use its then() method to ensure the map is centered before you open the popup.

Here's how you would update the selectState function to do this:

```
// fires when a row in the dgrid is clicked
function selectState(e) {
  // select the feature
  var fl = map.getLayer("states");
  var query = new Query();
  query.objectIds = [parseInt(e.target.innerHTML)];
  fl.selectFeatures(query, FeatureLayer.SELECTION_NEW, function(result) {
    if ( result.length ) {
      var center = result[0].geometry.getExtent().getCenter();
      // close the map's popup and clear features
      window.map.infoWindow.hide();
      window.map.infoWindow.clearFeatures();

      // re-center the map to the selected feature
      // once that completes, show the popup anchored to the center of the new feature
      window.map.centerAt(center).then(function() {
        window.map.infoWindow.setFeatures([result[0]]);
        window.map.infoWindow.show(center);
      });
    } else {
      console.log("Feature Layer query returned no features... ", result);
    }
  });
}
```

Full working example:  http://jsbin.com/UXaYidi/1/edit

Comment: it works!!! thx u very much!!!

Comment: This excellent sample and explanation really needs to go into the official docs somewhere. It is perfectly illustrates a frequent use case. The setFeatures() method was the key that was not obvious (to me) from the docs.

Comment: Only thing is that I wish they had callback functions for `infoWindow.hide()` and `infoWindow.clearFeatures();` Currrently it seems the waiting caused by the callback of `map.centerAt(`) is the only thing that prevents `.hide()` and `clearFeatures()` from completing out of turn after `setFeatures()` and `.show()` executes, undoing the setting and showing of the new popup.